# Anagram fills all the blanks

Tags: riddle, wordplay, no-computers, anagram

Continuing with the theme " Same word fills all the blanks" here is a riddle where the anagrams of ONE WORD fill all the blanks.

One concession: Apostrophe allowed.

NO using Anagram Solver or any help from computer please.

Here is the Newspaper Headline

> An innovator in ______ design, Mr. ______   _______  a ______  in _______  ______ house.

There are in total six anagrams. Hopefully there is only one solution.

Comment: What does the 'no-computers' tag mean?

Comment: Anagrams of “one word” or anagrams of some particular word?

Comment: @JyotishRobin: You can hover over the tag to read a short description. Many word problems such as "find the longest word whose letters are all musical notes" are easily solved by attacking huge word lists with a script and then the discussion is whether "cabbaged" and "fabaceae" are really words. (They are.) The tag tells you that you should try to find a solution with pencil and paper, which is much harder. (Of course it's just an appeal to your puzzler's honour: No-one can check how you got the solution.)

Comment: Neil W. Sorry for late reply. Anagram of same particular word

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess is

> An innovator in **skate** design, Mr. **Keats** **takes** a **stake** in **Kate's** **steak** house.

Comment: How did you get it Hexomino. I thought this would be hard

Comment: It is really helpful to get the solution explanation. It helps in designing better puzzles.

Comment: I was pretty confident the word needed to contain an 's' given that there is a verb following a singular subject and the hint of an apostrophe. Also, usually words with lots of anagrams are quite short, say between four and six letters, and tend to use the more common letters of the alphabet 't', 'e', 'a', 'r', etc. The main crux was then trying to find a word to go before house ('spare', 'store' and 'post' were other options I looked at) and finding something sensible to fit with "_____ a _____".

Comment: Nicely found hexomino! Your solution differs a single letter of my solution, I hope I pushed you into the right direction with that ;)

Comment: To be fair, I did read your solution before finding mine and often that does help jog the mind.

Answer (score 3):

Let us take the letters of:

> LEAST

This will give you an idea what you can do in this sentence.
I think it's hugely wrong, though, but hopefully it sets us all into the right direction. ;)

> An innovator in stela design, Mr. Tales stale a Tesla in Teals' slate house.